# SDL2 - Window cannot be reopened

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I am writing a simple SDL2 application with 2 windows.

The first window (`window` variable) is shown when the application starts, the second one (`window2` variable) is hidden.

**Expected behavior:**

I click on the first window, the second window pops up, then I close the second window.

And I can close and reopen the window as much as I want.

**Observed behavior:**

Once I close the second window, if I reclick in the first window, the second window doesn't appear as expected.

As stated in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43173040/sdl2-window-cannot-be-reopened#comment73421477_43173462): the window doesn't appear in my window manager (i.e. Wayland).

---

**The code:**

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main()
{
    SDL_Window* window, *window2 = NULL;

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("ONE", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                     SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        window2 = SDL_CreateWindow("TWO", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 
                      SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 320, 240, SDL_WINDOW_HIDDEN);

        if (window == NULL || window2 == NULL) {
            SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
            SDL_DestroyWindow(window2);
            return 1;
        }

        bool running = true;

        while(running) {
            SDL_Event event;
            while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
                if (event.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT) {
                    if (event.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE) {
                        if (SDL_GetWindowID(window) == event.window.windowID) {
                            running = false;
                        } else {
                            SDL_HideWindow(window2);
                        }
                    }
                } else if (event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN) {
                    SDL_ShowWindow(window2);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window2);

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [SDL bug](https://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2818) that may *or may not* have been fixed by [this patch](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/rev/7cfe088fafba).

Comment: can you please provide more details

Comment: I don't use this project anymore, so I can't test if the patch fixes my bug. I suppose it does, considering the description of the bug. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should call [SDL_RaiseWindow](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RaiseWindow) to place the second window on top of the other. 
From [lazyfoo's](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/36_multiple_windows/index.php) legendary SDL tutorials:

```
void LWindow::focus() 
{ 
//Restore window if needed 
if( !mShown ) 
    SDL_ShowWindow( mWindow ); 

//Move window forward
SDL_RaiseWindow( mWindow ); 
}
```

Comment: You mean the code example? Its supposed to illustrate the answer. You have to add the SDL_RaiseWindow function call after the SDL_ShowWindow.

Comment: No, I meant that the window doesn't appear in my window manager (i.e. Wayland) by *"the window is not even created"*. There is no chance a `SDL_RaiseWindow` could raise a non-existing window. I tried it anyway with no success...